# Using spring AOP aspect to intercept the methods?

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I am using spring AOP to intercept the methods. I have below configuration in my spring config file.

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
```

Aspect class:

```
@Aspect
public class MyAspect{

 @Around("execution(public * *(..))")
public Object doAction(ProceedingJoinPoint call) throws Throwable {

 //somelogic
}
```

Above method does not intercept **private** methods ?  what should i do to ask the aspect to intercept both **private** and **public** methods?

Answer (score 5):

Private methods may not be intercepted, as they may not be invoked through a proxy.

However, you could use native AspectJ weaving, as you can see on the point 8.8.4 of the following page:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-pointcuts-designators

Comment: Andres, any alternative to intercept private methods? Thanks!

Comment: Use AspectJ weaving http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.RC2/reference/html/ch07s08.html

Comment: can i use AspectJ using annotations?

Comment: To work with Spring AOP/AspectJ, do i need to write interface and implementation class? Or it can act on the class itself?

Comment: +1 The reference in the documentation is in the _Note_ [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-pointcuts-designators). You might want to add that to your answer.